# excel - merge cells including a zip code

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, worksheet-function, merge

I have the need to merge a bunch of cells that comprise an address (street, city, state, zip) into a single cell.  No problem except with the zip code.

The zip cell has only 4 digits for any zip that starts with 0.  So, I change it's format to be  Special -> Zip Code.  That makes the cell itself show the beginning 0, but the merged cell still does not show the leading 0.

Does anyone know how to get the leading 0 in the merged column?

Thanks

Evan

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Zip code in cell A1 you can use the formula `=TEXT(A1, "00000")` to format the Zip code as 5 digits wide with leading zeros and then merge that instead of the numeric version.

Answer (score 1):

See this question

[MS Word 2007 Mail Merge fails on ZIP codes with leading Zeros (eg. 01234)](https://superuser.com/questions/150908/ms-word-2007-mail-merge-fails-on-zip-codes-with-leading-zeros-eg-01234/151004#151004)